# TTPhotoViewController: deactivate rotation (no orientation landscape)

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, three20, ttphotoviewcontroller

In my project, I use the Facebook API "three20": https://github.com/facebook/three20/

How can I deactivate the auto rotation? The image and the thumbnails should always displayed in portrait and not in landscape mode.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:`

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation {
    return NO;
}
```

Comment: It works! I set "return NO;" in TTPhotoViewController.m and  TTThumbsViewController.m! Thanks!